# Unable to import data from excel for drop-down list

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver

[image: Drop-down List]

Here is the code below,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Industry_B-1")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Industry_I")).sendKeys(sh.getCell(2, 2).getContents());
```

i have tried out the below code still not working:

```
Select sel= new Select(driver. id( "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Industry_B-1" ));
sel.SelectByVisibleText(sh.getCell(2, 2).getContents());
```

For text field type it's working fine. Only for List fields it's not importing.

**HTML CODE BELOW**:-

```
<input type="text" style="color:#555555;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;cursor:default;" readonly="readonly" onkeypress="aspxEKeyPress('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Industry', event)" onfocus="aspxEGotFocus('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Industry')" onblur="aspxELostFocus('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Industry')" onchange="aspxETextChanged('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Industry')" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Industry_I" value="--Select--" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cbpAssociationNew$panelAssnDetailAdd$Industry" class="dxeEditArea dxeEditAreaSys     " autocomplete="off">
```

**HTML LINK:-**
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fZ-YuuYXlrJzFbRJ_oPOMycdMlloS66dPIYe6TJDfas/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also, show the HTML of the dropdown you are trying to interact with. Thanks.

Comment: Where is code which you are using to get data from excel?? Please share that.

Comment: @alecxe i have edited the above post with HTML code..you can check it

Comment: @Saravana : Please add the HTML code snippet of the dropdown along with all the options.

Comment: @Subh i have added the link containing the HTML code to the post...you can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see from the HTML code snippet, this is not a simple **Select dropdown** that can be worked out using **Select class**. It consists of tables and table elements.

So, to resolve this you've to do things:

**1-** Click on the dropdown table using the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Industry_I")).click();
```

**2-** Click on the dropdown item that matches the text so fetched from the sheet using below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='dxeListBoxItem' and contains(text(),'"+sh.getCell(2,2).getContents()+"')]")).click();;
```

**OR try using "Action class":-**

**1-** Click on the dropdown table using the below code:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cbpAssociationNew_panelAssnDetailAdd_Industry_I"))).click().perform();
```

**2-** Click on the dropdown item that matches the text so fetched from the sheet using below:

```
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='dxeListBoxItem' and contains(text(),'"+sh.getCell(2,2).getContents()+"')]"))).click().perform();
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not working..it clicks the clicks the dropdown list but doesn't select value from the excel

Comment: Do one thing.. Print the value that you're fetching from the excelsheet using the code `sh.getCell(2,2).getContents()`. What does it return?

Comment: yes it is printing the corresponding value from the excel sheet

Comment: **First, please try the second code again. Have fixed a problem there.** If it still doesn't work, **please add the HTML snippet of whichever option** you want to select from the dropdown.

Comment: I have edited the answer with two methods to click on the menu and its submenu item. Please see if either of them works. If they don't, please let me know what error(s) are you getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65928/discussion-between-saravana-and-subh).